# How to repeat rows in a matrix in C?

Tags: c

I want to draw an image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2oWh.png) (for size 8x8):

```
##..##..##..##..
##..##..##..##..
..##..##..##..##
..##..##..##..##
##..##..##..##..
##..##..##..##..
..##..##..##..##
..##..##..##..##
##..##..##..##..
##..##..##..##..
..##..##..##..##
..##..##..##..##
##..##..##..##..
##..##..##..##..
..##..##..##..##
..##..##..##..##
```

My code is:

```
{
    int rows, cols, i, j, k;

    scanf("%d", &rows);
    scanf("%d", &cols);

    k = 1;

    for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=cols; j++)
        {
            if(k == 1)
            {
                printf("##");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("..");
            }
            k *= -1;
        }

        if(cols % 2 == 0)
        {
            k *= -1;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
```

This code works good, but it's not like in the image!

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: *"This code works good, but it's not like in the image!"* - then I take issue with your first claim. Clearly it's not working so good.

Comment: In theory, at least, you should check that the two `scanf()` calls both return `1` to indicate that they succeeded.  You should also validate that the entered values are strictly positive (not zero or negative), and not too enormous (I'd put a limit of something like 30 on the upper-bound — it's tedious to show even that).

Answer (score 0):

That's the different approach to the solution. The core idea is to get a base string with 1/2 additional repetition of the pattern. Then you basically "shift" the string back and forth by two positions using pointer arithmetic (to manage the beginning of the string) and putting the null character `\0` where appropriate (to manage the end of the string).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;

    /* From the example provided I assume that the number of columns
     * and rows should be a multiple of 2
     * even though the OP hasn't explicitly mentioned it
    */

    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols);
    // input validation goes here

    // generating the base string
    // notice that the string is 2 characters longer than required
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * (cols + 1) * 2 + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < cols / 2; ++i) {
        strcpy(str + i * 4, "##..");
    }
    strcpy(str + strlen(str), "##");

    int n = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        n = i % 2;
        // switching back and forth between null character '\0' and '#'
        str[len - 2] = n * 35; //35 - ASCII code for a '#'
        // using pointer arithmetic we send to function either first element
        // or third
        printf("%s\n%s\n", str + n * 2, str + n * 2);
    }

    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDITED:** Generalized the solution for arbitrary (but even!) number of rows and columns.

Comment: Although the example image is for an 8x8 layout, the code in the question asks for the rows and columns to be entered.  Can you generalize your solution to work for arbitrary sizes?

Answer (score -1):

This code does what you ask for, I think.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int rows, cols;
  scanf("%d", &rows);
  scanf("%d", &cols);
  rows = rows*2;
  int k = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      if(k < 2 && j % 2 == 0) {
        printf("##");
      }
      else if(2 <= k && j % 2 != 0) {
        printf("##");
      }
      else {
        printf("..");
      }
    }
    k++;
    if(k == 4) {
      k = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The last row is not duplicated!

Comment: Well, I might need to know, more accurate rules then.
The last row is only duplicated when the row number is even in my code. With this code you can print exactly, what's on that picture. (with 16, 8 input)

Comment: Now it works, for 8x8 input, you just have to add a 2 multiplier to rows then